# how do I make the speak_text() treat the page number as an int?

Tags: python, file, integer, range

```
import pyttsx3 as pytts
import PyPDF2 as pypdf

def open_file(file_name):

try:
    pdf_file = open(file_name, 'rb')
    

except:
    print('file opening operation filed...')

pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
pages = pdf_reader.numPages
user_input = input("Start from page 1?\nEnter answer:\n\t> ")

if user_input.lower() == 'yes' or user_input.lower() == 'y':
    prefered_page = 1
else:
    prefered_page = input("Enter desired page number:\n\t>")

page = pdf_reader.getPage(int(prefered_page))

def speak_text(file_name, page):

    for p in range(int(page) -1, pages):
        speaker = pytts.init()
        txt = page.extractText()
        speaker.say(txt)
        speaker.runAndWait()

speak_text(file_name,page)


def home ():
    file_name = 'short_story.pdf'
    open_file(file_name)

home()
```

Answer (score 0):

`page` is a pdf page not a number, what you want to pass is the `preferred_page` variable instead:

```
def speak_text(file_name, page, page_num):
    for p in range(int(page_num) -1, pages):
    .
    .
    .
    .
```

```
speak_text(file_name,page,prefered_page)
```

also if you know that the user is gonna input a number you can cast it instantly:

```
    prefered_page = int(input("Enter desired page number:\n\t>"))
```